# How to make the .isalnum() method return True for only specific special characters?

Tags: python

I am coding a password analyzer with several properties, one being that the user's password must not have special characters (**@#$%^&***) except for **!** (exclamation mark) and **_** (underscore). I am using the `.isalnum()` method for this purpose but I cannot figure out a way to make it so it doesn't return True when **!** or **_** is used WITH any other special character (ex: *Python$* returns False but *Python_* returns True).
Here is my code:

```
password = input('Enter a password: ')
if not password.isalnum():
    if '_' in password or '!' in password:
        pass
    else:
        print('Your password must not include any special characters or symbols!')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most intuitive way is to check every character.

```
if not all(c.isalnum() or c in '_!' for c in password):
    print('Your password must not include any special characters or symbols!')
```

Comment: OP wanted the `"Python$_"` be OK.

Comment: @MarianD No, they want no special characters except `_` and `!`. The question is confusingly worded.

Answer (score 3):

This is one way. replace the `!` and `_` withe empty string and then check with `isalnum()`.

```
password = input('Enter a password: ')
pwd = password.replace('_', '').replace('!', '')
if pwd.isalnum() and ('_' in password or '!' in password):
    pass
else:
    print('Your password must not include any special characters or symbols!')
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way of checking it is by using regex

```py
import re
x = input('Enter a password: ')
t = re.fullmatch('[A-Za-z0-9_!]+', x)
if not t:
    print('Your password must not include any special characters or symbols!')
```

Comment: Note that `str.isalnum()` applies to all of Unicode, but `[A-Za-z0-9]` only applies to ASCII. `\w` is closer (and includes underscore), though I'm not sure if it's equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_pass_ok(password):
    if password.replace('_', '').replace('!','').isalnum():
        return True
    return False


password = input('Enter a password: ')

if not is_pass_ok(password):
    print('Your password must not include any special characters or symbols!')
```

By removing all allowed special characters, i.e. `_` and `!`:

```
password.replace('_', '').replace('!','')
```

it remains only to check for alphanumeric characters (`.isalnum()`).

Comment: It would help to provide an explanation of how this code works. Just a sentence or two would do.